# how return value from def __del__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning to program with Python and while doing so I thought of how the `def __del__` would return a value, so I created a class `Test` that just have a `str` method and tried to return it with `__del__`.

At first the script was fine but I don't know how to store it while working in IDLE:

```
>>> class Test:
def __init__(self,name):
    self.name=name
def __del__(self):
    ma=self.name
    print ("works ??")
    return ma
def __repr__(self):
    return "name:({})".format(self.name)
```

Comment: What's the point of returning something from a destructor? You never even call the `__del__` function.

Comment: If you were hoping to do `t = Test(); val = del t`, that's not how `__del__` works and it will be a syntax error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
You say "the script was fine", but you're describing an apparent usage that is a base syntax error.  "how to store it" isn't clear -- store in what way?

Comment: Why are you trying to get the `__del__` function to return a string? Are you just trying to see when the destructor is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally speaking, the way to return something from `__del__` is with `return`, exactly the way you're doing it. However, literally returning something from `__del__` is pointless. The return value doesn't go anywhere useful; the memory management system will receive the return value, ignore it, and discard it.

If you were hoping to do `t = Test(); val = del t`, then as wim says in the comments, that's not how `__del__` works. `__del__` isn't a `del` hook; `__del__` is called by the memory management system when an object is about to be reclaimed. `del t` just unassigns the `t` variable; it doesn't force object destruction or reclamation, and it has no way to receive information about any object destruction or reclamation.

To communicate information out of `__del__` in a way that other code could actually use it, you'd have to use a mechanism other than return values. For example, your object could have a destruction callback:

```
class Blah(object):
    def __init__(self, callback=None):
        self.callback = callback
    def __del__(self):
        if self.callback is not None:
            self.callback(self)

def notice_destruction(obj):
    print("Hey look,", obj, "is about to be destroyed!")

Blah(callback=notice_destruction)
```